# How to be creative with HTML Email Tables

Tags: sas, report, html-email, proc

I have computed a report from SAS EG that will be emailed to stakeholders. This will be automated, and I want more creative ideas to make this more presentable.
Please refer to the code,

```
filename output email 
from=("")
subject= "Update as at &RUN_DT."
to=("")

ct= "text/html"
type="text/html";
     
ods html body=output style=styles.festival ;
ods noproctitle;

PROC FORMAT;
VALUE WFMT LOW-0.500 = '#FF0000'
            0.519 - 0.994 = '#FFA500'
            0.995 - HIGH = '#008000';
RUN;

TITLE "Update as at &RUN_DT.";FOOTNOTE;
PROC REPORT DATA=HUBCRMS16 NOWD MISSING
STYLE(HEADER)=[FONT_SIZE=9PT BORDERSTYLE=SOLID BACKGROUND=#94b7ff FOREGROUND=BLACK BORDERWIDTH=1PX]
STYLE(COLUMN)=[FONT_SIZE=8PT BORDERSTYLE=SOLID BORDERWIDTH=1PX]
STYLE(REPORT)=[BORDERSTYLE=SOLID BORDERWIDTH=1PX];;
COLUMN EMPE_NM ASSIGNED TOUCHED TOUCHED_PRECENT UNTOUCHED UNTOUCHED_PRECENT OPEN OPEN_PRECENT SUCCESSFUL SUCCESSFUL_PERCENT DECLINE DECLINE_PRECENT UNSUCCESSFUL UNSUCCESSFUL_PRECENT CONTACTED CONTACTED_PRECENT UNCONTACTED UNCONTACTED_PRECENT _DUMMY;
DEFINE EMPE_NM / GROUP;
DEFINE ASSIGNED / FORMAT=COMMA32.;
DEFINE TOUCHED / FORMAT=COMMA32.;
DEFINE UNTOUCHED / FORMAT=COMMA32.;
DEFINE OPEN / FORMAT=COMMA32.;
DEFINE SUCCESSFUL / FORMAT=COMMA32.;
DEFINE DECLINE / FORMAT=COMMA32.;
DEFINE UNSUCCESSFUL / FORMAT=COMMA32.;
DEFINE CONTACCTED / FORMAT=COMMA32.;
DEFINE UNCONTACCTED / FORMAT=COMMA32.;
DEFINE TOUCHED_PRECENT / COMPUTED FORMAT=PERCENT9.2 STYLE={BACKGROUND=WFMT.};
DEFINE UNTOUCHED_PRECENT / COMPUTED FORMAT=PRECENT9.2 STYLE={BACKGROUND=WFMT.};
DEFINE OPEN_PRECENT / COMPUTED FORMAT=PRECENT9.2 STYLE={BACKGROUND=WFMT.};
DEFINE SUCCESSFUL_PERCENT / COMPUTED FORMAT=PERCENT9.2 STYLE={BACKGROUND=WFMT.};
DEFINE DECLINE_PRECENT / COMPUTED FORMAT=PRECENT9.2 STYLE={BACKGROUND=WFMT.};
DEFINE UNSUCCESSFUL_PRECENT / COMPUTED FORMAT=PERCENT9.2 STYLE={BACKGROUND=WFMT.};
DEFINE CONTACTED_PRECENT / COMPUTED FORMAT=PRECENT9.2 STYLE={BACKGROUND=WFMT.};
DEFINE UNCONTACTED_PRECENT / COMPUTED FORMAT=PRECENT9.2 STYLE={BACKGROUND=WFMT.};
DEFINE _DUMMY / COMPUTED NOPRINT;
RBREAK AFTER / SUMMARIZE;

COMPUTE _DUMMY / CHAR LENGTH=32;
    TOUCHED_PRECENT = _C3_ / _C2_ ;
    UNTOUCHED_PRECENT=_C4_ / _C2_;
    OPEN_PRECENT=_C5_ / _C3_; 
    SUCCESSFUL_PERCENT = _C6_ / _C3_;
    DECLINE_PRECENT= _C7_ / _3_;
    UNSUCCESSFUL_PRECENT = _C8_ / _C3_;
    CONTACTED_PRECENT= _C9_ / _C3_;
    UNCONTACTED_PRECENT= _C10_ / _C3_; 

ENDCOMP;
RUN;

ods html close;
ods noproctitle;
```

The Result: The areas highlighted in Yellow are not a cropping issue. The border doesn't align properly.
[image]

I need this table to be more presentable and stylish. The tool version is SAS EG 8. Unfortunately, I can't change it.

Comment: Where is the screenshot from (browser, outlook?) Show the code for custom format WFMT.  Can you reproduce the problem with a sashelp data set such as sashelp.class? Have you tried ODS PDF instead of HTML?

Comment: I have not tried ODS PDF. The screenshot is available in the link.

Comment: but then, it will go as an attachment right? I want the data to be in the email body.

Comment: "make it more pretty" is a very subjective question. Can you ask something more concrete? Can you share the resultant code, or is that irrelevant because the system generates it and you can't edit it after the fact? Can you make it vertical, as most emails are 600-700 pixels wide (~4 columns max), but infinitely tall?

Comment: EG itself is a client -- what version of SAS are you connected to (either locally or remotely (PROC SETINIT will tell you)). Do you get a similar visual hiccup if you send the output to a file instead of email? If you get a similar visual with a different ODS destination or a different style, then the issue may be side effects of WFMT. or other style overrides.  You can deep examine the issue by outputting a single row and then examining the raw html in the received mail.  Can you communicate the same information in a graph instead of a table?